# How to convert a HTML template into nopCommerce Site theme?

Tags: html, templates, themes, nopcommerce

i have a Random html website template and i need to apply it on my nopCommerce site as a theme  ,
pleas let me know if that is doable.

and dose any body recommend a good free nopCommerce template ??

Comment: ["4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this guide to understand how to create a theme [Designer's Guide](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/72/designers-guide.aspx)

You can find free themes here [Extensions and themes](http://www.nopcommerce.com/extensions-and-themes.aspx?category=4&price=10)